# Dynamically populating a DropDown Template Control in a Gridview

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, drop-down-menu

I have a GRIDVIEW with columns, one of which contains a CSV of possible values for the dropdown that must appear on each row.

```
   Private Sub GridViewParameters_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GridViewParameters.RowDataBound

        If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
            'Get value of third column. Index is zero based, to 
            'get text of third column we use Cells[2].Text
            Dim CellValue As Integer = Convert.ToSingle(e.Row.Cells(0).Text)
            Dim ntextbox As New TextBox
            Dim ncheckbox As New CheckBox
            Dim ndropdown As New DropDownList
            Dim CellType As String = Convert.ToString(e.Row.Cells(3).Text)
            'MsgBox(CellType)
            Dim DropDownItems(0) As String
            Dim cnt As Integer
            Dim marker As Integer
            Dim arraydim As Integer = 0
            'MsgBox(Convert.ToString(e.Row.Cells(2).Text))
            If Trim(CellType) = "select" Then
                'e.Row.Cells(2).Controls.Remove(ntextbox)
                'e.Row.Cells(2).Controls.Add(ndropdown)
                If Len(Trim(Convert.ToString(e.Row.Cells(4).Text))) > 0 Then
                    For cnt = 1 To Len(Trim(Convert.ToString(e.Row.Cells(4).Text)))
                        If Mid(Trim(Convert.ToString(e.Row.Cells(4).Text)), cnt, 1) = "," Then
                            'e.Row.Cells(2).Controls.
                            'MsgBox("lll")
                        End If
                    Next
                    arraydim = arraydim + 1
                    ReDim Preserve DropDownItems(arraydim)
                    DropDownItems(arraydim) = Mid(Trim(Convert.ToString(e.Row.Cells(4).Text)), marker + 1, cnt - marker - 1)
                End If
                e.Row.Cells(5).Controls.Item(5).Visible = False
                e.Row.Cells(5).Controls.Item(1).Visible = False
                e.Row.Cells(5).Controls.Item(2).Visible = False
                e.Row.Cells(5).Controls.Item(3).Visible = True 'select drop down
                'e.Row.Cells(5).Controls.Item(3).Controls.
            End If
            If Trim(CellType) = "textbox" Then
                'e.Row.Cells(2).Controls.Add(ntextbox)
                'e.Row.Cells(2).Text = Convert.ToString(e.Row.Cells(3).Text)
                e.Row.Cells(5).Controls.Item(5).Visible = True
                e.Row.Cells(5).Controls.Item(1).Visible = False
                e.Row.Cells(5).Controls.Item(2).Visible = False ' textbox
                e.Row.Cells(5).Controls.Item(3).Visible = False
                'e.Row.DataItem(
            End If
            If Trim(CellType) = "boolean" Then
                'e.Row.Cells(2).Controls.Add(ndropdown)
                'e.Row.Cells(2).Text = Convert.ToString(e.Row.Cells(3).Text)
                e.Row.Cells(5).Controls.Item(5).Visible = False
                e.Row.Cells(5).Controls.Item(1).Visible = True 'checkbox
                e.Row.Cells(5).Controls.Item(2).Visible = False
                e.Row.Cells(5).Controls.Item(3).Visible = False
            End If
            If Trim(CellType) = "hidden" Then
                e.Row.Visible = False
            End If
            'e.Row.Cells(2).Controls.Remove(ntextbox)

            '' If value is greater of 10, change format
            If CellValue > 0 Then
                ' Use this syntax to change format of complete row
                e.Row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightGreen
                e.Row.Cells(0).ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightGreen
                e.Row.Cells(3).ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightGreen
                'e.Row.Cells(5).ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightGreen
            Else
                e.Row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightPink
                e.Row.Cells(0).ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightPink
                e.Row.Cells(3).ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightPink
                'e.Row.Cells(5).ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightPink

                ' Use this syntax to change format of single cell
                'e.Row.Cells(2).BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
```

Depending on whether the type of control is a dropdown, textbox, or check box (feined in the table) it hides or shows the relevant control type. If it is a dropdown it needs to get its values from a CSV in a corresponding column. I have a SP that returns a these in table form if passed the id of the relevant row.

How do I get that is from the gridview to pass to the drop down and load it correctly?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So, if I read this right you're already reading the CSV value into the DropDownItems array, but you can't see how to take that array and fill the DropDownList from it, correct?

Well, a DropDownList can use an array as its' `DataSource`, so we can set the property and call the `DataBind` method, and we're done:

```
....
e.Row.Cells(5).Controls.Item(3).Visible = True

ndropdown.DataSource = DropDownItems
ndropdown.DataBind()
```

BTW, instead of parsing the CSV value yourself to strip out the commas, you can use the String.Split method to do the work for you:

```
'We can replace all this
For cnt = 1 To Len(Trim(Convert.ToString(e.Row.Cells(4).Text)))
    If Mid(Trim(Convert.ToString(e.Row.Cells(4).Text)), cnt, 1) = "," Then
    End If
Next
arraydim = arraydim + 1
ReDim Preserve DropDownItems(arraydim)
DropDownItems(arraydim) = Mid(Trim(Convert.ToString(e.Row.Cells(4).Text)), marker + 1, cnt - marker - 1)

'with
DropDownItems = e.Row.Cells(4).Text.Split(",".ToCharArray())
```